# How many new apps are added to the developer exchange in a given quarter?

Tags: appexchange

I don't know if lots of companies use the apps.  I don't know a lot about it, if it is a "vibrant" app store or if it is full of dead apps that Salesforce customers never even visit.  Is there a metric to look at to see if companies that use Salesforce actually use the app store?

Comment: There's more installs than customers, but... I don't know how well that translates.

Answer (score 2):

Salesforce claims that there are 2700+ apps in appexchange,
http://www.salesforce.com/platform/appexchange/
[image]